# Is it bad practice to use multiple location tags for authorization?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, authorization

I am wondering if it is bad practice to add a whole bunch of location tags for individual .aspx page authorizations?

```
<location path="mypage.aspx" >
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="User1,User5"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

I realize that you are able to specify the path as a directory, and then all of the pages within that directory use the authorization rules, however I would like the pages to stay in the root.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I agree, maintenance will get nasty, I am going to add roles and organize. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how granular your permissions need to be, but it will certainly be a maintenance nightmare.  If the entire site is set up that way, you couldn't pay me enough to maintain a site like that.

You're far better off assigning roles, assigning people to roles, and doing it at a folder level where possible, and page level where absoutely necessary.

The exception is, of course, if there are only a few pages like this and it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing inherently wrong with it other than you're creating a higher maintenance and more error prone situation by taking that approach.  If it's a site containing sensitive information, it would be wise to organize more thoroughly.

In addition, it would also depend on the number of pages the site contains.  If the whole site is 4 or 5 pages, that's one thing, but if it's 20-30 or more....yikes.